# Can stored procedures run in parallel inside a single Oracle session?

Tags: oracle

I'm particularly interested in the effect on package global variables. 
Those are session-scoped. But can I somehow change them from parallel execution contexts *inside the same session*?

Suppose I have the following package definition:

```
package package_with_global is
   acc integer := 0;
end;
```

Can I somehow execute stored procedure code in parallel that changes `acc`  like this?

```
declare
   acc_A integer;
   acc_B integer;
begin
   start_in_parallel do -- <-- does this exist?
     acc_A := package_with_global.acc;
     long_running_operation_A;
     package_with_global.acc := acc_A + 1;
   end;

   start_in_parallel do -- <-- does this exist?
     acc_B := package_with_global.acc;
     long_running_operation_B;
     package_with_global.acc := acc_B + 1;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Not how you are trying to do it.  Take a look here ...  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4248554900346593542

Comment: Can I make a suggestion? Perhaps you can define the problem that you are trying to solve, because I think you have may dived into a solution, without knowing all the possibilities.

Comment: Judging by @TheGrandDuke 's asktom link, it looks to me like the answer is "no". In the example, dbms_parallel_execute seems to create four different sub-sessions to do the work. The code in the end is executed in parallel, but not inside the same session. One session's acc will not be able to interfere with the other session's acc.

Comment: @BobC, I'm trying to debug a package global issue, not building a solution. I really need a yes/no answer here to rule out one of the hypotheses. Can you help me rephrase the question to make that clearer?

Comment: @ThiagoArrais. As the others have said, there is no "threading" as such from within a PL/SQL package. Two processes can run the same package concurrently.

Comment: Perhaps, if you explain the "package global issue" we may be able to help with your initial problem.

Comment: No need to. Your link already clarified this for me. It would be nice to see some official doc saying that one session necessarily corresponds to a single execution thread. But DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE doing parallel execution by opening multiple sessions is enough evidence for me. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is *no*. There is no threading inside sessions.

But you *can* execute code in parallel inside Oracle using the DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE package, as shown by [the link posted by @TheGrandDuke](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4248554900346593542).

The trick is DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE creates parallel *sessions* and runs each chunk inside a different session. The `acc` variable will have a different value inside each session, just like when you open two different connections.

Comment: Please _do_ downvote this if you find someway to execute multiple threads inside the same session.